How to host two django apps on windows using apache and mod_wsgi?
I know how to run 1 django application on windows server using mod_wsgi & apache. Now I want to run more than one django application on the same server.
I have the following configurations
httpd.conf
at the end of the file I added
LoadFile "C:/Python312/python312.dll"
LoadModule wsgi_module "C:/Python312/Lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp312-win_amd64.pyd"
#WSGIPythonHome "C:/Python312"

windows_wsgi.py for application app1
# Activate this path from virtual env
activate_this = "C:/Users/rahee/.virtualenvs/app1-jCWLzbvP/Scripts/activate_this.py"


exec(open(activate_this).read(),dict(__file__=activate_this))


import os
# import site 
import sys 
from decouple import config

# Add the site-packages of the selected virtual env to work with
# site.addsitedir = "C:/Users/rahee/.virtualenvs/app1-jCWLzbvP/Lib/site-packages"
sys.path.append("C:/Users/rahee/.virtualenvs/app1-jCWLzbvP/Lib/site-packages")
sys.path.insert(0, "C:/Users/rahee/.virtualenvs/app1-jCWLzbvP/Lib/site-packages")

# Add teh app directory to the PYTHON PATH
sys.path.append("C:/Apache24/htdocs/app1")
sys.path.append("C:/Apache24/htdocs/app1/app1")


os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = config('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE')
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

application = get_wsgi_application()

windows_wsgi.py for app2
# Activate this path from virtual env
activate_this = "C:/Users/rahee/.virtualenvs/app2-mArRrqZl/Scripts/activate_this.py"


exec(open(activate_this).read(),dict(__file__=activate_this))


import os
# import site 
import sys 
from decouple import config

# Add the site-packages of the selected virtual env to work with
# site.addsitedir = "C:/Users/rahee/.virtualenvs/app2-mArRrqZl/Lib/site-packages"
sys.path.append("C:/Users/rahee/.virtualenvs/app2-mArRrqZl/Lib/site-packages")
sys.path.insert(0, "C:/Users/rahee/.virtualenvs/app2-mArRrqZl/Lib/site-packages")

# Add the app directory to the PYTHON PATH
sys.path.append("C:/Apache24/htdocs/app2")
sys.path.append("C:/Apache24/htdocs/app2/app2")


os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = config('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE')
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

application = get_wsgi_application()

httpd-vhosts.conf settings

<VirtualHost *:92>
    ServerName app1.localhost
    WSGIPassAuthorization On
    ErrorLog "logs/app1.error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/app1.access.log" combined
    WSGIScriptAlias /  "C:\Apache24\htdocs\app1\app1\wsgi_windows.py" application-group=%{app1}
    <Directory "C:\Apache24\htdocs\app1\app1">
        <Files wsgi_windows.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    Alias /static "C:\Apache24\htdocs\app1\assets"
    <Directory "C:\Apache24\htdocs\app1\assets">
        Require all granted
    </Directory>  
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:91>
    ServerName app2.local
    WSGIPassAuthorization On
    ErrorLog "logs/app2.error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/app2.access.log" combined
    WSGIScriptAlias /  "C:\Apache24\htdocs\app2\app2\wsgi_windows.py" application-group=%{app2}
    <Directory "C:\Apache24\htdocs\app2\app2">
        <Files wsgi_windows.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    Alias /static "C:\Apache24\htdocs\app2\assets"
    <Directory "C:\Apache24\htdocs\app2\assets">
        Require all granted
    </Directory>  
</VirtualHost>

When I restart apache
When app1 is working, I got error on app2 that  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app1'\r and When app2 is working I got error on app1 that  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app2'\r

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback. It will be also more readable in question, and more people can see it - so more people may help.
